Evaluating Dimensionality Reductions models that can only transform train data
To evaluate the performance of dimensionality reduction (DR) models like TSNE and TRIMAP what I do is the following:

Fit a model on trained data and transform train data
Fit a new model on validation data and transform validation data
Use a 1-NN classifier or regressor to obtain a performance score on the data reduction

The reason for this is that models like TSNE and TRIMAP cannot do out of sample reduction.

Is there a better way to evaluate such models?

Some shortcomings I have noticed is that the different models might rotate or deform the data. In such cases notions of distance are not necessarily conserved hence nearest neighbours doesn't give a good measure of perforamnce.

If you need to do dimensionality reduction on a test set use a method which allows for this, rather than trying to hack your way to a solution.

@user2974951 I want to be able to evaluate methods that can only transform a single data set. That's why I'm asking if there are other methods superior to the one I proposed to achieve this

If you want to evaluate how a method performs at something it cannot do, I think you have your answer.
